# Why use <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source instead of plain T::AccountId?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

According to this [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/6042), all dispatchable calls should use `<T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source` instead of `T::AccountId`. Why is it better to handle transfers with the lookups instead of addressing users with their accounts? How the lookups in Substrate works, is there an alternative to the `StaticLookup`?

And lastly, are there any other types than the `IdentityLookup` and how would you use them?

```
type Lookup = IdentityLookup<AccountId>;
```

Comment: You should probably ask that question on the PR itself

Comment: @michaeldel That's probably true but I figured out that there might be a lot of people interested in this topic and it would be nice if they were able to find the answer via the SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

StaticLookup is an abstraction over an address which can convert multiple different address types into an underlying AccountId.

Imagine an extrinsic which uses only AccountId. The only way to interact with that function would be to provide the raw AccountId for the account on chain.

Instead, with StaticLookup, you are able to provide any compatible address format, and there will be additional logic that is used to then convert that address into an underlying account.

Imagine the following:

```rust
enum Address {
    AccountId([u8; 32]),  // 32 byte account id
    String(Vec<u8>),      // arbitrary string
}
```

This is a practical example of how you would allow people to use a name service on your chain. For example you can do:

```
transfer(b"shawntabrizi", 100 UNIT)
```

In addition to:

```
transfer(5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY, 100 UNIT)
```

StaticLookup will contain any appropriate code to convert from the known formats into the final AccountId you need.

Imagine the following code:

```rust
struct NameServiceLookup;
impl StaticLookup for NameServiceLookup {
    type Source = Address;
    type Target = AccountId;

    fn lookup(a: Address) -> Result<AccountId, LookupError> {
        match a {
            Address::AccountId(id) => Ok(id),
            Address::String(string) => {
                string_to_account_id(string).ok_or(LookupError)
            },
        }
    }

    fn unlookup(a: [u8; 32]) -> Address {
        Address::AccountId(a)
    }
}
```

Here you can see we have special logic that would handle the address if it was either an AccountId or a String. This is ultimately what `StaticLookup` would provide.

The implementation of `IdentityLookup` is a simple passthrough, which returns exactly the input for the output. So this would be what you want to use when you do not have any such fancy logic, and want to make all `StaticLookup` exactly the same as `AccountId` directly:

```
pub struct IdentityLookup<T>(PhantomData<T>);
impl<T: Codec + Clone + PartialEq + Debug> StaticLookup for IdentityLookup<T> {
    type Source = T;
    type Target = T;
    fn lookup(x: T) -> Result<T, LookupError> { Ok(x) }
    fn unlookup(x: T) -> T { x }
}
```